# Classify all groups of order $8836$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I need help sorting all order groups $|G|=8836=2^2 47^2$.

By Sylow I know $n_2 \in \{1,47,2209\}$ and $n_{47} = 1$ and therefore $G$ is not simple. I really don't know how to go about finding the $G$ isomorphic groups and the semi-direct products. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well the normal $47$-group is either cyclic $C_{2209}$ or $C_{47}\times C_{47}$ and a Sylow-$2$-subgroup is either $C_4$ or $c^2\times C_2$. That's four cases to consider. Can you do the easiest one where both are cyclic?

Comment: @ancientmathematician you mean when $C_4 \times C_{2209}$?

Comment: Have a look at the duplicates here at this site, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490441/non-abelian-groups-of-order-p2q2) and others. The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624991/classify-all-groups-of-order-p2q2-up-to-isomorphism) also works for $(p,q)=(2,47)$.

Comment: There are two groups when the Sylows are both cyclic, an abelian group (which you give) and one rather like a diherdral group. But @DietrichBurde has given you two good references.

Comment: @ancientmathematician The dihedral group because 8836 is even?

Comment: You are not following what I am saying so I will say no more. Look at the solutions suggested.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Since the Sylow-$47$ subgroup is normal, you're looking at semi-direct products: $S_{47}\rtimes S_2$.  But any group of order $p^2$ is abelian.  So, use the structure theorem on the Sylow subgroups.